# How can I set up the Trusty Desktop ISO for preseeding?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, preseed, debian-installer

With Precise, I used to create a USB stick using the so-called "Alternate" installer DVD with my own preseed.txt, update isolinux/txt.cfg with a new menu item that would pass my preseed file on the command line, and watch as the installer happily did all the right things to create a Ubuntu install on the hard drive of the machine I booted.

With Trusty, the 'alternate' image has disappeared.

Is it still possible to preseed a Trusty install, and if so, how do I get the d-i/ubiquity system to use my preseed file?

Answer (score 0):

Dave (the original asker of this question) and I came across the solution ourselves.

It turns out that if you start from the Server ISO (rather than the Desktop ISO we originally grabbed), you are already much closer to what we were familiar with from Precise.  All of the starting point Trusty images are [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).

Once we got the Trusty Server ISO image, everything was familiar, and the steps Dave outlines in the question worked as before.